# Flutter Form Builder with Date Picker. No named parameter with the name 'anchorPoint'. anchorPoint: widget.anchorPoint,

Tags: flutter, forms, datepicker

I have a strange problem, I used Flutter Form Builder before and I can't fix any issues but when I use it in other project this is occurred with me.

I cleaned my project and run flutter pub get then flutter run  but no thing is changed

this is complete error:
[`Error Image`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vx3CE.png)

```
FormBuilder(
    key: _formKey,
    child: Column(
      children: [
        FormBuilderTextField(
          name: 'age',
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            labelText:
                'This value is passed along to the [Text.maxLines] attribute of the [Text] widget used to display the hint text.',
          ),
          onChanged: (value) {},
          // valueTransformer: (text) => num.tryParse(text),
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        ),
      ],
    ),
  )
```

**Error**

> ../../FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_form_builder-7.2.1/lib/src/fields/for
> m_builder_date_time_picker.dart:355:7: Error: No named parameter with the name 'anchorPoint'.
> anchorPoint: widget.anchorPoint,
> ^^^^^^^^^^^
> ../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/date_picker.dart:133:19: Context: Found this
> candidate, but the arguments don't match.
> Future<DateTime?> showDatePicker({
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ../../FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_form_builder-7.2.1/lib/src/fields/for
> m_builder_date_time_picker.dart:373:7: Error: No named parameter with the name 'anchorPoint'.
> anchorPoint: widget.anchorPoint,
> ^^^^^^^^^^^
> ../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/time_picker.dart:2413:20: Context: Found this
> candidate, but the arguments don't match.
> Future<TimeOfDay?> showTimePicker({
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Answer (score 0):

add `form_builder_extra_fields: ^8.2.0` dependencies.